# html select menu keeps value when page is refreshed

Tags: php, html, select, drop-down-menu

Not 100% sure how to word this question but here goes, I am currently writing a small web application in html and php for a barcode scanner that has Internet Explorer on board. The page I am stuck on, allows the user to select a Location from a select menu in html and then scan a barcode. When the barcode is scanned, there is a Number feild where the data goes, this then submits the number to a php script which changes an item location in a database. But when this process is finished I send the user back and I have lost my Location selection.

This is a massive pain as the user would have to keep selecting that location when wanting to scan an item, this will not work when scanning 200 items in a time frame.

I have thought about sessions or using variables in the URL with get but I have an issue with initially setting the Location and possibly changing the location mid way through.

Please ask any questions if you need to, I hope this is descriptive enough,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post code , what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You could append the selected location to the URL when you submit your form (?location=selected_location) and then getting it when you redirect the user.

I hope this helps you! It would be also easier if you would post some code.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. my code is very unorganised at the moment and have deleted half of what I started with. I have decided to try and start again, using sessions mainly, I think the url is also a very good way forward. My head is completely scrambled!